# What's wrong with this function (R) (Beginner)

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function that automatically performs the group_by and summarize commands of dplyr on a particular dataframe (x) that has columns of interest (y).  The code I wrote is:

```
    mysummary <– function(x, y){
                     k = x %>%           
                           group_by(x$y) %>%
                           summarize(col.name = mean(var.name))
                     return(k)
                  }
```

This either doesn't work at all (saying there is no column called y if I just have y as the argument in the group_by function) or with current code above returns a tibble that is the same irrespective of what I group by (it's always grouped by the variable year in the dataset in this case, regardless of what I use as the y argument).  Can anyone help explain why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y` is the argument, then we don't need `x$y` inside `group_by`, it can be converted to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`).  The advantage is that it can take either quoted or unquoted argument for 'y'

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x, y) {
           x %>%
             group_by(!!ensym(y)) %>%
             summarize(col.name = mean(var.name))
     }
```

Here, we assume that 'var.name' as a column name in the dataset 'x'

Answer (score 0):

We can use curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

mysummary <– function(x, y) {
   k = x %>% group_by({{y}}) %>% summarize(col.name = mean(var.name))
   return(k)
}
```

and you can use this as :

```
data %>% mysummary(col_name)
```